# How to get ListView of a known ListViewDataItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, find

I have a lots of ListView(s) on my .aspx page. Inside of each ListView's ItemTemplate there is a checkbox, which onCheckedChanged calls a method. The method is the same for all checkboxes in their respective ListViews.

Inside of the method I have the code which gets the CheckBox object that fired the event and gets the ListViewDataItem that contains the CheckBox object:

```
// Gets the CheckBox object that fired the event.
CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
// Gets the item that contains the CheckBox object.
ListViewDataItem item = (ListViewDataItem)chkBox.Parent.Parent;
```

Now, I would like to go a bit further and get the "parent" ListView of the ListViewDataItem. But sth like:

```
ListView myListView = (ListView)item.Parent.Parent........;
```

is not working, probably because ListView is in different inheritance hierarchy than ListViewDataItem.

How would you get the ListView?

Any help is greatly appreciated
 Thank you
 Best regards

nickzde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using parent.parent.parent sounds like a code smell if you ask me.
Isn't it possible to assigne a value to the checkbox which you can use to identify the listview?

Comment: Thank you for answer. Your idea with the checkbox sounds good. I can name the checkbox in such a way that I can get the ListView name from it by casting checkbox name to string. But how will I then cast the string to ListView type? I need the ListView name for other manipulation to be done on the ListView.Many thanks, nickzde

Comment: Sorry for the late reply:
Not that it's that clean, but you could do a this.FindControl and pass the name of your listview, then you should be able to cast it. <br>
I'm not sure what you want to do with your listview but this might help you out

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly how I finally did it. I am marking your reply as answer. Best regards. nickzde

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView myListView = (ListView)item.NamingContainer;
```

**edit**

I would use this also for the item

```
ListViewDataItem item = (ListViewDataItem)chkBox.NamingContainer;
```

You avoid **Parent.Parent.Parent**

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Panel ID="pnSomeParent" runat="server">
     <asp:CheckBox ......
   </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
```